# C# web api route for a webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am coding a web api in c# and I have a question in regards to the correct route to access a function called `test`.

Here is the class definition:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class ItemsWebApiController : ApiController
```

I have a `RoutePrefix` as follows:

```
[Route("test")]
```

Here is the function called `test`:

```
[Route("test")]
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public String test()
{
    return "test";
}
```

I am trying to access the following url:
http://localhost/api/test

The above url is displaying the following exception:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /api/test

How can I access the `test` function, such that the string `"test"` is displayed in my browser?

**EDIT**

I have deployed to my local IIS, and the database connection strings are working correctly.

The address for the local IIS is http://localhost/

These are the urls that I have tried:

http://localhost/test

http://localhost/api/test

http://localhost/api/test/test

http://localhost/ItemsWebApiController/test

http://localhost/ItemsWebApi/test

All of the above return the error page.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `Route` prefix in your class as `[Route("api")]` as well? Otherwise I am not sure you access using "/api" in it.

Comment: It would be something like `http://address/api/ItemsWebApi/test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to activate Attribute Routing in WebAPI Controllers

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and in your application start

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

And then your URL is `http://localhost/test`, because the default route would not match here.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that the GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); was not at the top of the function.

Answer (score 4):

If you a putting `[Route("test")]` your url will be `http://address/test`

if you need url like `http://address/api/test`, change your route like `[Route("api/test")]`

**Note**: you need to add `[HttpGet]` as well

Answer (score 1):

The route based on your configuration will be: http://address/api/test/test
the first `test` is the route prefix from the attribute `[Route("test")]`; 
the scond `test` is the action in the controller from the attribute defined on the method

```
[Route("test")]
public String test()
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Web api infers the http method based on your action name. It won't know from "Test" what to use.

See [the docs](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#add-routes)

**HTTP Methods**

Web API also selects actions based on the HTTP method of the request (GET, POST, etc). By default, Web API looks for a case-insensitive match with the start of the controller method name. For example, a controller method named PutCustomers matches an HTTP PUT request.

You can override this convention by decorating the mathod with any the following attributes:

- [HttpDelete]
- [HttpGet]
- [HttpHead]
- [HttpOptions]
- [HttpPatch]
- [HttpPost]
- [HttpPut]

The following example maps the CreateBook method to HTTP POST requests.

```
[Route("api/books")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateBook(Book book) { ... }
```