# C# Web API Route Prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api that runs in a WPF C# application. I have used Owin to implement it. If I send request by using `/api` prefix then it works as I expected.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/test/config?no=7
```

However, I need to remove the /api prefix. If I try the request below it does not work when I tried example code below.

```
http://localhost:8080/test/config?no=7
```

Is it possible to remove api word from requests?

Here is my code:

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: "http://*:8080/");

    class Startup
    {
        Type ValuesControllerType = typeof(TestController);

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder Builder)
        {
            var Instance = new HttpConfiguration();

            Instance.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            Instance.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{request}",
               defaults: new { request = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

            Builder.UseWebApi(Instance);
        }
    }

    [RoutePrefix("test")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {    
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("config")]
        public string Config(string No)
        {
            try
            {
                return No;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried the answer in [C# web api route for a webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987742/c-sharp-web-api-route-for-a-webservice) but did not work.

I get following error:

```
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

Comment: Could you show en error when `[RoutePrefix("test")]`?

Comment: I edited the question. I get Service Unavailable error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Rest api open your WebApiConfig.cs you should find the following code:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

Try removing api from there

Comment: that's odd acording to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772816/remove-api-prefix-from-web-api-url) it should work. is the line `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` still enabled. and if you place a debug point in the `webapiconfig.cs` does it still go in there or do you only get into your owin class?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem in .Net Core 2 WebAPI project

here is my solution

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    [Route("getUser")]

    public IActionResult GetUsers()
    {
         return Ok();
    }
}
```

the address is `http://localhost:port/default/getuser`